# Extract HTML title in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

Suppose I have a URL like `www.google.com`, and I want Javascript/JQuery on my page to go see what is in the `<title>` for the content of that URL, and put it into a variable for me. How can I make it work?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228947/how-to-get-current-html-page-title-with-javascript

Comment: Are You loading the URL in the browser, or just want to know the title for it?

Comment: @xyu I just want to know the title for it.

Comment: As noted by Xander in his answer, if the page you're wanting to look into is not in the same domain as your page (and I'm pretty sure www.google.com isn't!!) then you will hit the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which will remove your ability to do this on the browser itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

given the url is of the same origin:

```
$.get('page.html', function(text) {
    var pagetitle = $(text).title;
});
```

Comment: +1, although given the question uses google.com as an example, I have my doubts that he's looking at a URL in the same origin.

Comment: @Spudley I see. I'm looking at URLs both in the same and in different origins. So should I do this on the server side for URL in different origins?

Comment: @john see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131210/work-around-for-the-same-origin-policy-problem

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like:

```
var title = document.title;
```

After seeing your edited question I guess what you wanted as the others remark is:

```
jQuery.get('<url of the page you want>', function(data) {
    var title =  jQuery(data).title;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
   var title =  $(html).title
});
```

Comment: You can't use `.get` to load arbitrary URLs.  They need to obey the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var titles    = document.getElementsByTagName('title')
```

try to det title from url

```
$.get(document.URL, function(demo) { //or window.location.href to get the url of currec\nt page 
    var title = $(demo).title;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work for you. I'm not sure how a `match` compares, performance-wise, against the other options here:

```
var html_title = html.match("<title>(.*?)</title>")[1];
```