# Detect frame location/content changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame

I have the following situation. I have 2 frames (top and bottom). The upper frame monitors the current loaded page in the bottom frame. How can I know if the users changed the location of that frame (the url)? So I want to know when the user, press a link in that page, that goes somewhere.

I found something like this here: [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-div-content-changes-with-jquery) , but it doesn't help me (I think).

Could you give me some ideas?

Thanks,
Timotei

**EDIT:** The bottom frame is on another domain, so according to this: [Jquery permission denied - different domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222687/jquery-permission-denied-different-domain-name) is not possible.

So, to put it other way, is there any method to "monitor" the pages a users surfs, using any other in-browser method?

Comment: Are the frames in the same domain?

Comment: @Nick: No. The frame contains a textbox, which will have introduced (by the user) an URL. The bottom frame will browse to that location.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this, for security reasons it's prevented.  You could set the frame's domain and poll the frame, but not get an event when it changes.

Comment: @Nick: you were right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222687/jquery-permission-denied-different-domain-name .  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe can store the location of the iframe, then create a interval that will look if the SRC has changed.

```
var theSrc = document.getElementById('myframe').src;

setInterval(function(){
  if (document.getElementById('myframe').src != theSrc) {
    // the URL has changed
  }
}, 5000);
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: It doesn't work. After I read another bunch of documents it seems impossibe to do what I want because of some security policies. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222687/jquery-permission-denied-different-domain-name