# Error to call web service with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, xmlhttprequest, apache-axis

Hi i have created an html page with this javascript function

```
           function getData() {
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.onreadystatechange=sendData;
                    req.open("GET", "http://service-page/axis2Example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/services/SystemService/viewUsers?positionX=10&positionY=30&round=10", true);
                    req.send();
                }
            }

            function sendData() {
                if(req.readyState==4 & req.status==200) {

            }
        }
```

This function is used to call a web service. The problem is that my browser answer with this message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ........ autoCreate=false&log=true. Origin ...... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Does anyone knows a solution?

Comment: You cannot fire off an ajax request to a protocol/server/port different from the one that the code initially loaded from. Unless your browser is physically sitting at `http://service-page`, it'll probably be considered a cross-domain request and blocked for security reasons.

Comment: As for the solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to enable CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) in your ajax targeting server.

you can find more info here
http://enable-cors.org/server.html